Could a quantum computer have any advantage in counting the number of Penrose tilings of a subset of the plane?
I was watching a recent (as always beautifully produced) video by Grant Sanderson on his 3blue1brown channel.  He describes a number of interesting puzzles, the first of which ponders how to best tile a subset of the plane with a rhombus having internal angles of $(60^\circ$,$120^\circ,60^\circ,120^\circ)$ degrees:

In particular he asks about the diameter of the graph generated by rotations of three rhombuses meeting at a point:

Because all of the rotations are reversible, I began to suspect that a quantum algorithm could address some of the questions posed in the video; for example, with a qubit at each edge of the equilateral triangular lattice, a continuous-time quantum walk along this graph could be implemented by trotterizing the rotations, and phase estimation thereof would let us sample from the spectrum of various starting tilings.  For example flipping from one orientation of three rhombuses to another orientation thereof is an involution and we can take the roots of these moves easily enough.
Alas, the point of Sanderson's video is that for the specific $(60^\circ,120^\circ,60^\circ,120^\circ)$ rhombus, going up to three dimensions to consider moving boxes around lets us easily count the number of such tilings - growing as $n^3$ with $n$ rhombuses.  So at least with the rhombus tilings, a quantum computer wouldn't tell us anything that some simple pondering would tell us.

Nonetheless we all know and love the famous Penrose tilings:

Penrose tilings exhibit five-fold symmetry, and we can consider a very similar quantum walk.  I think we can use generators based on some decagons within the tilings:

With this setup, I can ask my main question - namely, as opposed to the rhombic tiling considered by Sanderson, what would it take to show that a quantum computer has any advantage to counting the number of Penrose tilings of a subset of the plane?
Are the generators amongst all of the decagons necessary and sufficient for any rhombic Penrose tiling?
